# If I add some KOH, where will the reaction shifts?

Tags: equilibrium, coordination-compounds

I just got a final test and one of the question is:

$\ce {Ni^2+}$ + 6$\ce{NH_3}$ $\ce {<=>}$ $\ce{[Ni(NH3)6]^2+}$

If we add some aqueous $\ce{KOH}$ after the reaction reach equilibrium, where will the reaction shifts?

Comment: What are your initial thoughts?

Comment: Think about complex stability, NH3 dissociation equilibrium and Ni hydroxide precipitation.

Comment: @jonsca i think NH3 is a base and KOH is a base, so it looks like add NH3 on reaction, so the reaction will shifts to right

Comment: I think @RauruFerro has the right idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equilibrium will shift to the left, as $\ce{Ni^2+}$ is removed from the equilibrium by the precipitation of $\ce{Ni(OH)2}$:

$$\ce{Ni^2+ + 2 OH- \rightleftharpoons Ni(OH)2\downarrow}$$

The precipitate forms when $[\ce{Ni^2+}]$ and $[\ce{OH-}]$ are sufficiently high to exceed the solubility product of $\ce{Ni(OH)2}$ ($K_{sp}=5.48 \times 10^{-16}$ at 25 °C, [source](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~franzen/public_html/CH201/data/Solubility_Product_Constants.pdf)). The concentration of $\ce{Ni^2+}$ before addition of $\ce{KOH}$ depends on the [stability constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_constants_of_complexes) of the ammin complexes (there are several species in equilibrium with each other, as the ligands are exchanged stepwise, and not all at once). Nickel hydroxide will dissolve again when $\ce{NH3}$ is added, as this shifts the equilibrium of ammin complex formation to the right.